# Gunicorn under supervisor keeps restarting

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

Working on `Ubuntu` vm.

I set up `gunicorn` (supervised with `supervisor`) behind `nginx`. gunicorn runs my flask app. I noticed that gunicorn keeps on restarting after every second or so. An excerpt from the `Tail -f Stderr` on the supervisor web console shows the following:

```
23-10-09 13:52:46 +0000] [8201] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:47 +0000] [8201] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:49 +0000] [8202] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-10-09 13:52:49 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:49 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:50 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:50 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:51 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:51 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:52 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:52 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:53 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:53 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:54 +0000] [8202] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:55 +0000] [8203] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-10-09 13:52:55 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:55 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:56 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:56 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:57 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:57 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:58 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:58 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:52:59 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Connection in use: ('localhost', 8000)
[2023-10-09 13:52:59 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2023-10-09 13:53:00 +0000] [8203] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('localhost', 8000)
<SNIP>
```

Excerpt frpm the `supevisord.log`

```
2023-10-09 14:47:31,872 INFO exited: microblog (exit status 1; not expected)
2023-10-09 14:47:32,875 INFO spawned: 'microblog' with pid 8909
2023-10-09 14:47:33,971 INFO success: microblog entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-10-09 14:47:39,004 INFO exited: microblog (exit status 1; not expected)
2023-10-09 14:47:40,008 INFO spawned: 'microblog' with pid 8912
2023-10-09 14:47:41,088 INFO success: microblog entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-10-09 14:47:46,122 INFO exited: microblog (exit status 1; not expected)
2023-10-09 14:47:47,125 INFO spawned: 'microblog' with pid 8913
2023-10-09 14:47:48,216 INFO success: microblog entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-10-09 14:47:53,249 INFO exited: microblog (exit status 1; not expected)
2023-10-09 14:47:54,254 INFO spawned: 'microblog' with pid 8969
2023-10-09 14:47:55,348 INFO success: microblog entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-10-09 14:48:00,378 INFO exited: microblog (exit status 1; not expected)
2023-10-09 14:48:01,381 INFO spawned: 'microblog' with pid 8970
2023-10-09 14:48:02,478 INFO success: microblog entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2023-10-09 14:48:07,509 INFO exited: microblog (exit status 1; not expected)
2023-10-09 14:48:08,512 INFO spawned: 'microblog' with pid 8971
```

These are the contents of my `supervisor` `microblog.conf` file:

```
[progranumicroblog]
command=/home/xxxx/flask-mega/venv/bin/gunicorn microblog:app -b localhost:8000 -w 4
directory=/home/xxxx/flask-mega
user=xxxx
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

The flask app being served runs fine but encounters errors in some locations.

Where do I start looking to fix the error?

Comment: supervisord logs are a step away from where you likely need to be looking. If you're working from the Flask Mega Tutorial, see the part about Logging in part 7.